# Getting 2d coordinates from igraph-python

Tags: python, coordinates, igraph

i have a code generating network with igraph, and i would like to retrieve 2d coordinates (Xs and Ys) of nodes (i don't need edges) to be able to plot results in other space, lets say with JavaScript. Here is a code example for visualizing network from numpy matrix:

```
import igraph
import numpy
A = numpy.zeros(shape=(5,5))
A[0] = [0,1,1,1,1]
A[1] = [1,0,1,0,1]
A[2] = [1,1,0,1,0]
A[3] = [1,0,1,0,1]
A[4] = [1,1,0,1,0]
g = igraph.Graph.Adjacency((A > 0).tolist())
g.es['weight'] = A[A.nonzero()]
igraph.plot(g)
```

is it possible to retrieve coordinates, preferably without visualizing network in python, lets say in dictionary? Can it be done with some other package, something like pygraphviz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not interested in the plot itself, just call any of the layout functions (there are several, the one called simply `layout` pointing to the default, IIRC), all of which return a `layout` object with a `coords` attribute that contains x and y positions.

```
layout_obj = g.layout()
x, y = np.array(layout_obj.coords).T
```

Comment: haha :) simple and it works very well, only it should be not "layout.coords" but "layout_obj.coords" . Thanks a lot mate

Comment: Good catch; fixed the answer.